# Notification or delegate method when dismissing UIStoryboard segue-based modal view controller

Tags: uiviewcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

I have 2 UIViewControllers in a storyboard.  The first one segues to the second one via an IB-defined "Modal"-style UIStoryboardSegue with transition type "Partial Curl".

This works as expected.

I would like to take some action to configure the first viewController when the UIModalTransitionStylePartialCurl completes.  There is a -prepareForSegue:sender: method, but although that is called when *beginning* the curl, it is *not* called when dismissing the curl.

Yes, I have subclassed both view controllers and overridden this method to verify this.

My theory is that the particular segue, or perhaps all modal segues, work a different way.  Maybe they parallel all "Modal" view controllers lifecycles?

If that is the case, then there is probably something like "willPresentModalViewController" and "didPresentModalViewController" notification or delegate method, but I **can find no mention of it**.

So, my question is, **how can I get notified that the modal view controller is being dismissed**?

Comment: Does viewWillAppear method of first view controller gets called when you dismiss second view? If yes, then you could use for example nsuserdefaults variable, that will keep track, which view is currently presented and check it's value in viewWillAppear to do additional stuff.

Answer (score 0):

Since iOS 5, you can use the completion block available in the method presentViewController: or dismissViewControllerAnimated:

```
[self presentViewController:(UIViewController *) animated:(BOOL) completion:{
    //called after the view controller is presented
}]

[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL) completion:^{
    //called after the view controller is dismissed
}];
```

The completion block will behave similarly to "didPresentModalViewController" or "didDismissModalViewController".

For the "willPresentModalViewController" or "willDismissModalViewController", you can just put your codes before calling the methods above.